# Button change sized using Mouse

Tags: wpf, button, resize, mouseevent

I would like to know if there is a way to resize a button Width using the mouse, like when you are in the design mode, I'd like to change the cursor to the resize cursor when the mouse pass over the edge of the button, and with a sutained click resize the button.

thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) for this.  Here is an article on Code Project that describes how to "drag, resize and rotate elements on a Canvas", with and without Adorners: [WPF Diagram Designer: Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)

Comment: Wow, seems like this is a very good aproach !! I'll test it in the weekend .. Thanks !!!